# moving files in order dependant on file name with powershell

Tags: powershell, filesystemwatcher

I use PS script with filesystemwatcher to monitor a folder. In this folder files need to be picked up in a specific order, not in the order they are created. So:
Files "blabla-Important1.xml", "blabla-Important2.xml" and "blabla-Important3.xml" are placed in the "pick-up folder". Filesystemwatcher wants to move the files according to the script. Now I need the files to be placed in the "destination folder" in the order I want, let's say:

"blabla-Important2.xml",
"blabla-Important4.xml",
"blabla-Important3.xml",
"blabla-Important1.xml".

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Here's the (partial) script:

```
$folder = '.\tstA'
$filter = '*.xml' 
$destination = '.\tstB'
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
IncludeSubdirectories = $false              
NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
}
$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
$path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
$name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
$changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
$timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
Write-Host "$timeStamp The file '$name' was $changeType and moved for SFTP to $destination"
"$timeStamp The file '$name' was $changeType and moved for SFTP to $destination" | Set-Content 
'.\tst.log'
Move-Item $path -Destination $destination -Force -Verbose                  
}
```

Comment: If you want the files to be shown in the File explorer in a certain order, you should not only move them, but at the same time provide a new filename that will ensure the order you want. Something like `001blabla-Important2.xml`, `002blabla-Important4.xml` etc.

Comment: Hi Theo, thanks for your answer. The files will be offered in random order in the "tstA" folder, but need to be moved(and uploaded) in a specific order from "tstB". No need for showing in a specific order in Explorer.